# Multiple Links < a > accessing the same JQuery Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple links in my page rendered from the database. All of them I gave the same ID and created an JQuery click function taking from that id. Im trying to run a simple test calling an alert but it doesn't work. Ins't it suppose to work? Is there a better approach?

```
$("#lkResumeIt").click(function () {
    alert("resume it");
});

<a id='lkResumeIt' href='#' contentID='1'>Item 1</a>
<a id='lkResumeIt' href='#' contentID='18'>Item 2</a>
<a id='lkResumeIt' href='#' contentID='22'>Item 3</a>
...
```

The code below using class selector workd fine when the elements are static, but when they are dynamically they dont. see actual code below:

```
<script language="javascript">

$("#divContent").on('click', 'a.linky', function (event) {
    alert("resume it");
});




            function RunIt() {
                $("#divContent").html("");
                var jsongo = '';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Controller/FollowingPaused/',
                    data: jsongo,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                            var htmlCode = "<a href='/Controller/Details/" + msg[i].ID + "' style = 'float: left;'><img class='packageImage' border='0' src='" + msg[i].Size0Path + "' /></a>";
                            htmlCode += "<span style='float: left;margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;'>" + "<b>" + msg[i].TheName + "</b><br>";


                            if (msg[i].IsPaused == true) {
                                //htmlCode += "<a href='/Controller/Resume/" + msg[i].ID + "'>Resume</a>";
                                htmlCode += "<a href='#bar' class=linky contentID='" + msg[i].ID + "'>Resume</a>";
                            } else {
                                //htmlCode += "<a href='/Controller/Pause/" + msg[i].ID + "'>Pause</a>";
                                htmlCode += "<a href='#bar' class=linky contentID='" + msg[i].ID + "'>Pause</a>";
                            }
                            htmlCode += "</span>";
                            htmlCode += "<div class='clear'></div>";
                            $("#divContent").append(htmlCode);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


RunIt() 

</script>



        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div id="divContent" style="display: table-cell; line-height: 1.5;">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IDs cannot be duplicated. If you want one hook for jQuery, use `class`, which CAN be duplicated.

Example:

**HTML:**

`<a href="#bar" class="linky">Foo</a>`

**JavaScript:**

```
$("a.linky").on('click', function (event) {
    alert("resume it");
});
```

**For dynamically-created elements:**

```
$("#your-static-wrapper-element").on('click', 'a.linky', function (event) {
    alert("resume it");
});
```

Comment: thanks, but the code doesn't work when the html is generated dinamucally, for instance: $("#divContent").append("<div class='main'></div>")

Comment: @EdwinSoho It will, actually. You just need to adjust the selector.

Comment: I understood your dynamically-created answer, I applied that and didn't work, I edited my question to make it more clear. If it is static it works wonderfully

Answer (score 4):

You cannot Use same id twice because:

Your code will not be valited by W3C, what means that you can have headaches with your website's compability accross browsers. It can works fine in one browser and in other not.

You can use

```
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
$(".main").click(function(){
$(this).something..
})
```